# Is it possible to set a value of an embedded chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I noticed that some charts have other charts embedded within them.  For example, https://github.ibm.com/IBMPrivateCloud/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-dsm-dev includes an embedded chart for db2.

I was hoping to set a value for the embedded chart from the command line using a `--set` argument, but unfortunately it seems like that only applies to the parent chart's values.

Is it possible to set a value that is used in the embedded chart or do I need to clone it all locally to edit those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set subchart values using a --set. Use `--set subchartName.key=value`.

Please see [overriding values of a child chart](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals.md#overriding-values-of-a-child-chart)

**Chart.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "0.1.0"
description: A monitoring Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: "monitoring"
version: "0.1.0"
```

**requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: grafana
  version: "2.3.0"
  repository: "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com"
```

**Example:**

```
helm template . | grep -A1 "spec:" | grep type
type: ClusterIP
```

**Using** `--set subchart.key=value`

```
helm template . --set grafana.service.type=NodePort | grep -A1 "spec:" | grep type
type: NodePort
```

Comment: Thanks!  I swear I looked all over in the docs before posting that yesterday, but I must have missed this valuable guide.  In my case the subchart was embedded and so there was no requirements.yaml but I think I read that the "subchart" name should always match the directory name under `charts`.  I was also reading about the special "global" chart values which automatically apply to subcharts.  Lots to learn!

Answer (score 1):

You can, i.e. if the requirement is db2 and you want to set a custom image, it would be `db2.image=whatever`

If you are using an alias for your requirement, then use the alias name instead of `db2`